# Function to return modified SF Symbol in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have written the following function which interprets a given "weather code" value and maps it to an image. Then I modify that image with the `.foregroundStyle` modifier.

```
func weatherImage(weatherCode: Int) -> Image {
    switch weatherCode {
    case 0:
        return Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill").foregroundStyle(Color.Orange)
    case 1:
        ...
    case 9: 
        return Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill").foregroundStyle(Color.white, Color.blue)
    ...
    }
}
```

The idea is that I could call this function from my Views in manner similar to the following example and render images with uniquely different `foregroundStyle` modifiers on the fly:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        weatherImage(weatherCode: 0)
    }
}
```

However, doing so does not return an `Image`, but rather `some View` leading Swift to complain about the return type and it suggest adding `as! Image`. I have done so and then the code compiles, but at run-time this still leads to a casting error (`SwiftUI.ModifiedContent` versus `SwiftUI.Image`) and SIGABRT.

Can my solution be salvaged or is there a better way of handling this programmatically and getting these modified symbols displayed in a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the function, so it returns a `View` and not an `Image`.

Add a `@ViewBuilder` at the beginning, remove the `return`s, remember to provide a default case.

```
    @ViewBuilder
    func weatherImage(weatherCode: Int) -> some View {
        switch weatherCode {
            case 0:
                Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill").foregroundStyle(.orange)
            case 1:
                ...
            case 9:
                Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle.fill").foregroundStyle(Color.white, Color.blue)
            default:
                EmptyView()
        }
    }
```

In the view, just call the function:

```
weatherImage(weatherCode: 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work, but it appears to render the Image as a raster, causing it to blur when resized. Is there any way to maintain the vector graphics?

Comment: Add `resizable`

Comment: I've managed to do this by modifying the function to `func weatherImage(weatherCode: Int, size: Int)` and sizing the image as a vector before returning it as raster.